# How do I make relative file pathing work with include()?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm working on a website, and the relevant portion of my file structure is:

- site

  - classes

    - class1
  - js

Now, the js contains scripts that use other scripts within the same folder.  The only way I can get the scripts to load properly on the php pages is to either copy the whole js folder into the relevant subfolder, or move the page to the site folder.  Neither of these options is good.
I know that the issue is with the file pathing, so how do I get the includes in the js scripts to path relative to their location, and not the location of the php page?

An example of this:
I have a page in class1 called class1home.php.
It calls a js script called script.js.
script.js contains a function with include(script2.js), which is in the js folder.
Because of the pathing, the include is looking for site/classes/class1/script2.js.
I want it to go to site/js/script2.js.

Because there are multiple folders and scripts using script2.js, I can't just change the filepath within the include to be relative to that specific page.

Within script.js:

```
/**
 * @function      Include
 * @description   Includes an external scripts to the page
 * @param         {string} scriptUrl
 */
function include(scriptUrl) {
    document.write('<script src="' + scriptUrl + '"></script>');
}
```

One place it is used (within script.js):

```
/**  
* @module       ToTop  
* @description  Enables ToTop Plugin  
*/  
(function ($) {
    var o = $('html');
    if (o.hasClass('desktop')) {
        include('js/jquery.ui.totop.min.js');

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $().UItoTop({
                easingType: 'easeOutQuart',
                containerClass: 'ui-to-top fa fa-angle-up'
            });
        });
    }
})($);
```

Comment: who understand the question?

Comment: I think some sample code might help us understand and also help someone provide a useful answer

Comment: I have updated the question with an example

Comment: Can you share some code? The function definition for `include` (a poor function name choice) would be helpful, as well as where it is being called.

Comment: You need to look into Require.js or yepnope.js or something like that. What you are using there won't work, because the script will likely not have been downloaded by the time the you call the function defined within it.

Answer (score 0):

I normally solve this type of problem by having the page identify where it is with a call to Server.  It looks like this:

```
$callingPageURL =$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
```

Then, I parse that string to determine the file and the folder, by using the explode function.  It looks like this:

```
$callingPageURLHolder = explode("/", $callingPageURL);
```

This loads up an array of values into callingPageURLHolder.  From there, I use common data structure methods, like array pops, to get to the part of the URL that I think will be relevant to the program.  It looks like this:

```
$callingPageFile = array_pop($callingPageURLHolder);
$callingPageFolder = array_pop($callingPageURLHolder);
```

Once you can parse out the array that comes back from Server, you could simply load up variables you need to concatenate into a URL that you will call in your include.

This same type of technique can be used to make small changes in a template page based on where it was included from, by adding in some flow control that tests these kinds of extracted values.

For example,

```
    switch ($callingPageFile){
    case "index.php":
    // some response
        break;
 }
```

Using logic like that, I might build chains of cases in which I respond to anticipated URL parts.  I use this type of code for when I might want to slightly customize a PHP page.  Using these techniques, and some planning, you might be able to respond to the idea that you intend to transplant your code to a variety of places.